# TEdgeBrowser devtools elements copy menu empty

Tags: delphi, tedgebrowser

Delphi 10.4.1 TEdgeBrowser. Seemingly for no reason, the Elements -> Copy menu only shows 'Empty', not the expected 'Copy Element', Copy Selector, Copy JS Path, etc. The Edge Beta browser installed on the server also has the same issue. My local PC's Edge browser (also Beta) has the full 'Copy' menu, but my Delphi app does not.

I have no idea what I could have done to break it. Prior versions of my Delphi app also gives same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

--Stan

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This doesn't answer your question but is important: The latest Delphi release 10.4.2 has a revamped TEdgeBrowser component, supporting the Microsoft released version (10.4.1 support only the preview code named "canary").

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My 10.4.1 was working great with the 'Beta' Edge installed. Just stopped working yesterday -- no updates to the server, and no changes to the Delphi build options.

Comment: Maybe you have installed Edge release? Or a Windows Update removed the beta "canary" version?

Comment: Just did a full ininstall of all Edge versions on my local pc, rebooted, installed Canary. No joy. Canary browser has the 'Copy Element' functions, but not when I run my Delphi app (after deleting the 'MyDelphiApp.exe.WebView2' .folder)

Comment: Use SysInternals ProcessExplorer to see which DLL it is loading. Maybe it doesn't load the canary version for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. ProcessExplorer reports its loading the WebView2Loader.dll in the exe folder. But again, the regular Edge (Canary) browser doesn't nave a copy menu.

Comment: WebView2Loader.dll is an Edge loader. I don't know if canary already had it.